# How to use development.js, production.js and test.js in CompoundJS

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use CompoundJS in one of my application.
I am experienced with Rails and have used configuration files like `config/environments/development.rb` etc.,

But now i am trying to place configuration data in CompoundJS for each environment and utilize it
in the controllers. How do i achieve this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `config/environments/*.js` files. Configure your express app here as usual: `app.set('key', 'val');`. In controller you can access your config as `compound.app.get('key');`.